# When can I use infinitive "be" after WH question words?

Tags: bare-infinitives, wh-questions

I watched 'Pirates of the Caribbean: The Curse of the Black Pearl' yesterday, and I've heard some phrases which include 'be' after question words in the bare infinitive form. For example: "Where be Jack's hat?"
How does it work, what is the structure, and what are the rules of using this structure?

Answer (score 1):

This is either archaic or dialectal, so the short answer is "you can't".

"Where be Jack's hat?" is ungrammatical in standard English.

This use of "be" may a feature of West Country dialect: according to Wikipedia, "*be* may be used exclusively in the present tense [in West Country dialect], often in the present continuous; *Where you be going to*?".  The West Country (southwest England) is historically associated with pirates, and the West Country accent is the stereotypical "pirate" accent.

Comment: The following usage is from Jack the Giant Killer, dating back to at least the 18th century.                                                                                                                              Fee-fi-fo-fum,
I smell the blood of an Englishman,                                                                          
Be he alive, or be he dead
I'll grind his bones to make my bread.  A version later appears in Shakespeare's KING LEAR                                                                                          https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fee-fi-fo-fum

Comment: That is familiar, now that you mention it - although I interpret the usage in "Be here alive" as subjunctive (an inverted alternative to "Whether he be alive"), whereas I think "Where be Jack's hat?" is a dialectal use of the indicative (but it might just about be possible to parse it as subjunctive = "where might Jack's hat be?").  Whether it is indicative or subjunctive is of limited practical relevance, because "Where be Jack's hat?" is clearly non-standard.  "Be he alive or be he dead..." might still be considered standard but is a literary or semi-archaic use.

Comment: Agreed on both counts!